# Bluetooth BLE Beacon, Advertise

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, ads

when starting with this Bluetooth low Energy (BLE) development, i come across some questions:

- with my development board, I can send out *advertisement* beacons, they are recognized by Windows 7 (Bluetooth, Add Device). The demo application on the board sends out beacons which are in length <31 bytes. In this data there is included the data for length, an ID byte and a string.

But how is Windows able to identify the Bluetooth device address (BD) and the name of my device? This data is not included in the advertisement beacon, but I cannot find any document which describes how this data is transported.

So the relevant data is:
the **Beacon** .. the **BD address** .. the **device name**

Comment: I think beacons use standard BLE advertisement packets which DO include the address.  The beacon data is embedded in the advertisement packet which includes the address.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth MAC address is sent in the header of any packet a BLE device transmits. This is added at the hardware layer, so you probably do not realize it is happening.

Similarly, when a BLE device is configured with a local name, it is transmitted by the chip automatically in a separate advertisement packet.  Since this packet also had a header with the MAC address, the receiving chip uses this address to align the received name/MAC with any other packet received for that MAC.

This is how the Windows device knows the name and MAC for your received advertisements.